# Extract specific JSON from log file in Python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to extract particular JSON from log file which contains multiple JSON and normal text, in this case I am trying to extract JSON containing "Output payload" text. I have tried multiple ways but not able to extract required JSON, the file is in the format:

```
[2020-05-17 15:32:11.698000] INFO [worker-1] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor [[cloudhub-us-claim-services-1-0-0-prod].post:/claims/{claimNumber}/predictionScores:experience-claims-predictionscore-api.config.7.771]: PredictionScoreAPILogger-7c506940-987d-11ea-9ef4-0a5226a8e24f:16634746: Initialization: Request successfully logged to mirror queue
[2020-05-17 15:32:12.190000] INFO [worker-1] org.mule.transformer.simple.MessagePropertiesTransformer [[cloudhub-us-claim-services-1-0-0-prod].experience-claims-predictionscore-api.prediction-details-claim-updates.stage1.839]: Property with key 'response', not found on message using 'null'. Since the value was marked optional, nothing was set on the message for this property
[2020-05-17 15:32:12.192000] DEBUG [worker-1] aiml.logging.debug [[cloudhub-us-claim-services-1-0-0-prod].experience-claims-predictionscore-api.prediction-details-claim-updates.stage1.839]: PredictionScoreAPILogger-7c506940-987d-11ea-9ef4-0a5226a8e24f:16634746:Datarobot API Call: Output payload received from Datarobot API: {
  "prediction": "N",
  "predictionScore": 0.0000629713,
  "predictionExplanations": "lineItem : 0|feature: ADJER_CANNOT_COMPUTE_TWG_SUGGESTED_TIME_ZERO|Value: Y|strength: -1.4469371757,\nlineItem : 1|feature: ADJER_CANNOT_COMPUTE_TWG_SUGGESTED_PRICE|Value: Y|strength: -1.1968554807,\nlineItem : 2|feature: MONTHS_DIFF_CLAIM_REPAIR_FACILITY_FIRST_CLAIM|Value: 61|strength: -1.0681064444"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably read the file as text and then parse it with regex. Something like this:

```py
import re

logfile = open(logfilepath, 'r')
log = logfile.read()
logfile.close()
objects = re.findall("(Output payload.*:\s?)(\{\s?[\s\S]+?\s?\})", log)
```

I have tested the regex for your given sample and it works fine. So this piece of code should work too. Once you get all the JSON objects, you can easily find the one you are looking for.

Happy hacking :)

Edit: Modified the regex according to the modified question. The regex now looks for an "Output payload" string.

Comment: Code gives error "unterminated character set at position 28"

Comment: Updated the answer and tested it. It should work now. :)